# GitLab API: filter jobs from pipeline by its name

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, cicd

I have a URL on GitLab API which has the next structure:
`gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:proj_id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs`

Now I want to get only one job with the next name: "rpm:build".

Request like `gitlab.com/.../jobs/?name="rpm:build"` returns me the whole batch of jobs.

So what should I do to get only one job?

Answer (score 1):

can you pipe to JQ? as described from the cookbook:

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key

something like this:

```
curl -L gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:proj_id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs \
| jq -c '.[] | select(.name | contains("rpm:build"))'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, I got the same result including all of the `id`'s from all of jobes (no filter).

Comment: oh maybe i misunderstood. so i guess you need the first finding only?

Comment: you can filter the list like this:
`jq -c 'first(.[] | select(.name | contains("rpm:build")))'`
you can also replace `first` with `nth(n)` or `last`